# Is there a way to update Blender without deleting it and downloading the new version?

Tags: versions, osx

I like to stay up with the latest version of Blender. I use Blender on my Macbook Pro and it is kind of a pain to update Blender because you have to delete it and then re-download it.

This isn't a huge deal but is there a way that you can just update Blender without deleting it and re-downloading it every time? It is kind of ridiculous to just re-download the entire program when the new version consists solely of bug patches.

Comment: Ridiculous?, for bug fixes? I would think not. ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Blender doesn't have an (auto-)update function that would do this for you.

Some years ago I experimented with a way to create binary patches - that works pretty ok, but the experiment never took further form, as an entire infrastructure to support this needs to be created, and for such an effort no resources have been found (people willing to work on it, maintain it and the servers).

Until that day you'll just have to download the entire program. Note that you don't have to install Blender, you can just run it from the location you downloaded and extracted it to (at least on Linux and Windows, so assuming it works also on OS X).

Comment: Yes, also on OS X, extracting and dragging to the Applications folder works fine. :)

Answer (score 3):

That isn't possible with the binaries. However, you could do that with the source code.

You could download the source code from the repository and compile it by yourself. With this method, you only need to download the files that changed. If you choose to do this, you will need to compile Blender each time you update your code which is more time consuming than just installing it.

Comment: Looks like shooting mosquito with canon ;)

Comment: @PhoneixS Why binaries can't be updated?

Comment: @iamcreasy Normally when you think in updating a binary what you do is replace the binary, not change it only what have changed because in binary a minor change could be all bytes modified. Instead in source code you normally can break it in lines, so you only need to update lines that have been changed. Although, you can still have binary parches if changes are little, this are very used in applications crack. I have tried to answer you, but I think that my answer isn't so clear :D

Comment: @PhoneixS Yeh I got it. But why they don't have a system that updated the binaries...Many closed source software do it. right?

Comment: @iamcreasy, I think that principally because they don't have enough time and resources to do it.

Comment: Which is faster depends entirely on the speed of your pc and internet. I have a fast pc but snail-paced net, so compiling takes a couple minutes where downloading a new build often takes over an hour.

Answer (score 3):

I heared that you can install [Blender via Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/365670/) and it should be updated automagically.

Comment: Can you confirm?

Comment: Yep... https://steamcommunity.com/app/365670/discussions/0/618460171315633543/#c618460171315922595, https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-best-way-to-update-Blender/answer/Francisco-Mateus-2, http://www.leadwerks.com/werkspace/topic/12513-blender-now-available-on-steam/#entry90245, http://www.blendernation.com/2015/04/25/blender-is-now-available-on-steam/

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/39296/2843

Answer (score 2):

If your on Ubuntu (or some linux distro with automatic updates, basically all of them), you can choose to download the latest development build. You'll get the updates then. If your interested, here's a link: http://mbah.net/2010/11/11/installing-blender-2-55-beta/

Comment: Broken link.  :(

Answer (score 2):

If your OK with using the buildbot dailies, you can use BlenderUpdater application:

https://github.com/tobkum/BlenderUpdater

Answer (score 1):

You can [install Blender via Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/365670/Blender/), which has a built in auto-update feature.

This should keep your Blender installation up to date automatically.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/overmindstudios/BlenderUpdater/releases/tag/1.9.2?fbclid=IwAR3D3TPfIJ4xhP2W0z_0Kg-FO3Z3_d3IAHLFTsdF1Bc3yHAnx_NeT8iYLU4

After googling for a while, found this blender updater program.

Works for me!

[image: Screenshot of Overmind Studios Blender Updater program]