# Why is the Steam version of Blender taking so long update?

Tags: installation, versions

I got the Steam version of Blender hoping to get new updates downloaded automatically but it's been days since 2.76 has come out but I still haven't gotten the update.

Are steam updates delayed for some reason? Do they have to go through a review or something? Is there a way to manually update Blender for Steam through downloading it from the website?

There's nothing I can find through Google about this since it's probably not a thing a lot of people complain about, so I thought this would be a good place to ask.

Thanks!

Comment: 2.76 official has not yet been released, still an RC

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise that makes sense. Didn't realize that only it was the release candidate available for download. My fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely due to the fact that Blender 2.76 is not officially released yet. What is currently available for download is the second release candidate. If it doesn't work as expected when the official release comes out feel free to update this question.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. Was wondering why everyone was posting about the 1.76 and the new features.