# Updating to latest Blender version

Tags: versions

I currently have version 2.74. How do I update to version 2.76? I do not see any links in the UI to update my version of Blender

Comment: Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/269/is-there-a-way-to-update-blender-without-deleting-it-and-downloading-the-new-ver

Answer (score 18):

You can [install Blender via Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/365670/Blender/), which has a built in auto-update feature.

This should keep your Blender installation up to date automatically.

Comment: great! And seems like the latest version is released on Steam the next day after the official site release

Answer (score 12):

There is no automatic update feature inside Blender that I'm aware of. But getting the latest version is very simple - just go to the [download page](http://www.blender.org/download/) of Blender.org and download the latest version.

Another easy method is to click "Blender Website" under the "links" section on the application splash screen.

[image]

Comment: ps - in my haste, I used the 2.76 application splash screen. However, the "Blender Website" link is there on the 2.74 splash screen as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Seems like there would be an Update link in the app. This is about the only application I have seen that does not provide an easy way to get updates :-)

Comment: Yeah, it would be nice to have an auto update feature - most software does. But with the simplicity of downloading a single zip file or .exe to get a fully working new version, I can't say I mind too much.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

If you're on a Mac and using Homebrew you can install/update Blender via:

```
# Install
brew cask install blender

# Upgrade
brew cask upgrade blender

# Upgrade (all casks)
brew cask upgrade
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find any official Blender verison [here](https://download.blender.org/release/).

Just select the version you want and the system you are running it on.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed Blender using Snap packages on a Linux machine.
( Step to use snap package can be found here: https://snapcraft.io/blender)

**To install using Snap you can use the following command on terminal:**

`sudo snap install blender --classic`

*Note: We need to have 'snapd' package already installed.*

**And, to update Blender using Snap you can you the following command:**

`sudo snap update blender --classic`

*Note: If you already in version 2.80, there would be no update available as 2.80 is the latest stable release*.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Dotbow's Blender Launcher for years.

[Blender Launcher](https://dotbow.github.io/Blender-Launcher/)

[image: Blender launcher]

A lightweight open source software that allows you to easily manage Blender installations, notifies you whenever a new version is published and downloads/installs it in a single click. Can work with stable, daily, experimental and custom builds, and is especially handy when you want to have multiple installations at once.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the `.zip` file from https://www.blender.org/download/ and it works. I now have two versions on my system and they work without interfering each other.

Answer (score 0):

This is a script to quickly install/update Blender to the latest daily build.  Note that these builds are likely to be somewhat unstable and buggy but will provide the newest updates available.

```bash
mv blender* previous_blender
blender_beta=head
blender_alpha=tail
xz=https://builder.blender.org$(wget -O - https://builder.blender.org/download/ | \
  grep -io '<a href=['"'"'"][^"'"'"']*['"'"'"]' | \
  sed -e 's/^<a href=["'"'"']//i' -e 's/["'"'"']$//i' | \
  grep linux64 | \
  $blender_beta -n 1)
echo $xz
wget $xz
tar xf blender*.tar.xz
rm blender*.tar.xz
mv blender* blender
cat blender/blender.desktop \
  | sed -e 's@^\(Icon=\)\(.*\)@\1'"$PWD/blender/"'\2.svg@' \
  | sed -e 's@^\(Exec=\)\(.*\)@\1'"$PWD/blender/"'\2@' \
  > $HOME/.local/share/applications/blender.desktop
update-desktop-database $HOME/.local/share/applications/
```

Comment: The binaries from builder.blender.org are the experimental daily builds, likely not what the average user wants/should be using.