# Find and Install Current Blender Release

Tags: installation

I don't know the correct place for this question so I'm asking here:  I have a previous version of Blender that I downloaded but was never able to use (extended illness).  I would now like to download the current version and would like to know what the latest version is and I'd like to know if I have to delete the version I already have.  Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50956/if-i-get-the-latest-version-of-blender-will-i-lose-anything-in-my-old-project-f/50963#50963 or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28949/if-you-install-blender-while-there-is-an-existing-copy-does-it-uninstall-the-ex/28953#28953

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6744/is-it-advisable-to-update-blender-to-the-newest-version-as-soon-as-possible-each and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41123/updating-to-latest-blender-version

Answer (score 1):

You Can keep the current version but it's quite useless.

There are three current builds:

- the main: **2.78c** that you can download from the official website under download.

> [https://www.blender.org/download/ù](https://www.blender.org/download/%C3%B9)

The last two are for advanced users they are unstable, so do not save any important file with this versions:

- 2.79 testbuilds (**2.78.5**), downloadable from here:

> http://graphicall.org/110

- 2.8 Testbuilds (**2.8**), downloadable from here:

> https://builder.blender.org/download/ under the red rectangle (2.8 project)

Answer (score 1):

If you go to https://www.blender.org/download/ you can get the latest release version.

You don't need to uninstall previous versions you might have in your system.