# How do you download Blender 2.79

Tags: versions

This is Yusamac205. I have been going through all of these different links that are supposed to download Blender 2.79 beta. But am unable to do it.

**Here are the links I have tried, with the explanation why they do not work:**

https://builder.blender.org/
This site even tells you that you will be downloading Blender 2.78

http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/
This site says that you will download Blender 2.79. But when I download it, it shows Blender 2.78.

https://developer.blender.org/
This site is confusing and does not seem to have any Blender 2.79 downloads.

https://miikahweb.com/en/blender/builds
Does not have anything beyond Blender 2.71.

http://graphicall.org/
This site does not provide Blender 2.79.

[Where can I get Blender test builds?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3438/39509)
I got a lot of the links that do not work from this question.

[Find and Install Current Blender Release](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/85036/39509)
None of those links work either

Comment: The reason it shows 2.78 is because it's not an official release.  A quick way to tell that you have 2.79 is by looking at the Render Layers tab in the Property panel.  If you see Denoiser at the bottom, it's 2.79.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A release candidate can be downloaded at  https://builder.blender.org/download/

[image]

From the [release Notes:](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.79)

> As the 2.79 is an important release before the transition to the 2.8 series, **please help Blender by testing the available builds and reporting possible issues.**
>
> **Compatibility Warning**
>
> When using add-ons in Blender 2.79 that take advantage of the new data-block pointer properties, the resulting .blend files can't be opened in earlier versions of Blender. Attempting to open such .blend files in Blender 2.78c and earlier may crash.

Where should I report bugs? [Read this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports)

Comment: Thank you so much @cegaton. You are priceless to the Blender Stack Exchange community.

Answer (score 1):

Just enter this link in your browser and it'll auto-download it for you!
https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/blender-2.79-testbuild2-windows64.zip

If you're not a Windows user, download the suitable version for you from here:
https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/

Comment: I do not have windows. I use iMac

Comment: try this:   https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/blender-2.79-testbuild2-OSX-10.6-x86_64.zip