# Blender crash when try to render with AMD GPU

Tags: rendering

I'm fairly new to Blender and I've been trying to speed up my rendering time by using my GPU, but every time I go to render my project, Blender closes without any warning or error message. I'm only trying to render a picture at the moment, and my PC should be able to handle it, so I can't figure out why it keeps crashing.
Here are some specs of my PC:

Edition - Windows 10 Pro

Processor - AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor 4.00 GHz

Graphics Card - AMD Radeon RX 460

Ram- 16GB

I'm using Blender 64-bit version 2.78

Comment: Try Blender 2.79-RC2. If that also crashes, write a bug report at https://developer.blender.org

Comment: Also try to open Blender the from [console](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21772/how-to-view-the-system-console-message-after-blender-crashes), it likely writes something there but you don't see it. Generally it all depends on that picture you're trying to render. Try with simpler / default scene, if that one works but the desired one - doesn't then Blender might be out of VRAM.

Comment: How do I try Blender 2.79-RC2?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86420/how-do-you-download-blender-2-79